# why my image not in center of div

Tags: html, css

**Why my image not in the center(Horizontally, Vertically) of div.**

```
<div>
   <img id = "loader-img" class="centered" alt src="al.gif">
</div>
```

and my css is:

```
.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
   }
```

Here is how my image looks like in div:

[image]

Comment: You could set a width and height for the image and get it to display `block` then `position: absolute: top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;`. Remember to set position relative on the parent when using this method. This will insure your image is in the center.

Comment: @Ruddy its also displaying not in the center of div(

Comment: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmpzp7ue/), look here.

Comment: @Ruddy Also not working. I include in my project bootstrap, may be bootstrap is acting here?

Comment: What about text-align:center on the parent div? And then you can strip out alot of code from .centered. Another option could be css table layout.

Comment: @lharby I added text-align:center to my .css file and i get another view, but it's also not centered: [image](http://imgur.com/rhCdnx4)

Comment: There are 3 answers in this thread that all work. Is there something else in your css which is overriding the css rules you are trying to apply? I would strip out the .centered class properties and start with something really simple. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/48o5zd7g/ (thanks to Zakhar Day). I think you need to share more of your code possibly, or make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @lharby Write your answer as answer, not as comment, and i will note your answer as answer for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
.frame {
    height: 125px;      
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center; margin: 1em 0;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class=frame>
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://www.afew-store.com/js/vigoshop/ajaxcart/ajax-loader.gif" height=250 />
</div>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/4arnv8r4/)

Update: As you say that above is the image which you are using then please note that given image itself is not good. As it has white background so its difficult to notice the difference.

I am drawing border around image and posting here again:

[image]

Comment: i posted my image above. This image not changed

Comment: Can I suggest you clear the cache when refreshing your code, the above example works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div>
   <img src="al.gif">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

And also, your id attribute contains space symbols. You should remove them:

```
<img id="loader-img" class="centered" src="al.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

CSS:

```
#logo{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
```

HTML:

```
<div>
   <img id="logo" src= {{image.get('logo').url()}}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested, this is my solution:

html

```
<div>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/100x50' />
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    background: pink;
    height: 200px;
}

img {
    margin:auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/lharby/48o5zd7g](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/48o5zd7g) (thanks to Zakhar Day).

There are 3 answers in this thread that all work.

There could be something else in your css which is overriding the css rules you are trying to apply? I would strip out the .centered class properties and start with something really simple.